Ubuntu Only Opens in Console Mode
To start, I'm running Ubuntu 24.04.4. I recently tried switching from KDE Plasma back to gnome. I (somewhat naively) ran the command
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt purge kubuntu-desktop && sudo apt autoremove

and upon rebooting my machine I only had access to console mode. I can get a gui environment by running startx but I'd like to be able to get the default GUI menu upon starting the machine. Any suggestions?

sudo apt install gdm3 will install GNOME display manager. It should fix your issue.

As above. The likely reason this happened is you kept the Kubuntu's default display manager - SDDM - when asked (you should have changed to GDM) and the next command purged it along the other desktop removal.
